# How to create the text effects in short videos like this

Tags: video

I would be very glad if someone could put me in the right direction as to how to achieve text effects like this:

I've researched and still can't make out how to create them easily on OSX.

Comment: You need tobe a bit more specific. What part of the process do you need help with: pre-production, shooting, editing, sound mixing, motion graphics, colour grading, etc.?

Comment: Google for "kinetic typography" or "text-based videos".

Comment: I wouldn't really call that a kinetic typography video though. It's just some supers on a video background. But googling is probably something the OP needs to be doing anyway.

Comment: Which effect do you want to achieve? Do you want to know how to shoot this style of video? How to make it a square? How to make the text? How to make the logo on the top right?

Comment: I was mostly interested in the text effects. Thanks for input everyone. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to create something similar to this with iMovie on your Mac.
You will simply gather all of the video clips you want to use, the music you want, and then plan out your text (in a [storyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storyboard) if it's easier). Make sure your video and music is licensed for you to use (not stolen from someone else or used without permission).

You can find lots of resources for stock videos, like [this](https://videos.pexels.com/).
You can find lots of stock music [here](https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary/music).
You can research about [lower thirds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7-bfAfAhzI) for the text effects at the bottom.

Of course, there are lots of other ways to achieve this, and tonnes of resources. But this is where you can start to achieve something like the video you provided.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This answered my question. I was mostly interested in lower thirds text effects :)